# Not able to call the php function using jQuery:ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am new to php and trying to implement a small webpage part of a school project. reportBuffering method in video.js file should call bufferingEventLogger method in server.php using Jquery ajax and store the passed values in Database. I am not able to trigger the bufferingEventLogger function. Here's the code for video.js

```
var video;
$(document).ready(function(){
var timeBuffered = 0;
var timer;
    video = $('#main-video')[0];
    video.play();
    $(video).on("play",function(){
    if(timer!=null)
        clearInterval(incrementBufferedTime);
    });
    $(video).on("waiting",function(){
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        incrementBufferedTime
    },1000);
    });
function incrementBufferedTime(){
    timeBuffered++;
    console.log("Buffered time"+timeBuffered);
    if(timeBuffered > 5){
        reportBuffering()
    }
}
function reportBuffering(){
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "server.php",
      data:{functionId:'bufferingEventLogger',val0:1,val1:'2016-04-18 16:37:01',val2:'2016-04-18 16:37:02'},
      success:function  (response) {
        console.log(response)
      }
    });
}
reportBuffering();
```

});

Below code is for server.php

```
$id=$_POST['val0'];
$bufferStartTime=$_POST['val1'];
$bufferEndTime=$_POST['val2'];

//bufferingEventLogger($id,$bufferStartTime,$bufferEndTime);

function bufferingEventLogger($id,$bufferStartTime,$bufferEndTime){
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "metrics");
$sql = "INSERT INTO buffer_time(id,buffer_start,buffer_end) VALUES   $id,'$bufferStartTime','$bufferEndTime')";
echo 'entered';

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

}


mysqli_close($link);
```

I have gone through similar questions, but couldn't get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only line that calls bufferingEventLogger is commented out.

Do you want to only call this function?  If so, just uncomment the line.

If you want to add more functions, you might need to use something like a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

@beating_around_abush You are almost there! What you are doing now is passing the function name from the client to the server (as part of the AJAX call). However, on the server side the data is received as a string. What you need to do on the server is take that string value and convert it to a callable definition (in this case a function call). Conversely, in the PHP file just before `mysqli_close($link);` add a call to bufferingEventLogger() specifically. It does mean you have to refactor the function definition but that is a quick change.